# Fernet from cryptography.fernet raises InvalidToken on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, cryptography

I'm using Fernet from cryptography.fernet in Python 2.7 to decrypt some data (~25k large list of strings). Everything is fine when I run it locally (data comes out just as it came in), but when I run it on my flask app in Heroku Scheduler, it throws an InvalidToken error.

The documentation is fairly cryptic (haha). It offers the following explanation:

> cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken – If the token is in any way invalid,
>   this exception is raised. A token may be invalid for a number of
>   reasons: it is older than the ttl, it is malformed, or it does not
>   have a valid signature.

```
key1 = Fernet(environ.get('env1'))
key2 = Fernet(environ.get('env2'))

f = MultiFernet([key1, key2])

contents = f.decrypt(bytes(data))
```

Normally, my list of data comes out fine, but on Heroku with the same cryptography libraries and version of Python 2.7, it throws InvalidToken like I've said above.

Is this a problem with Heroku running out of memory, hence the data is "malformed" when it's truncated? I'm on a Hobby dyno. Not sure what else it could be. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should not be an out of memory issue. Generally when something like this is happening it is due to encoding / decoding issues. In this case the way the token is stored and the `bytes` function is highly suspect (as it is missing an explicit encoding).